# Print array in a loop with dynamic variable Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, math

I am trying to define an array that increased by one each time then print the result of an equation that the array is assigned to;

my code so far is

```
public class PrimeNumberCounter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Define integers
int a = 1;
final int b = 2;
final int c = 3;
// Define Array
int[] nth;
nth = new int[100];
//Set loop
    for (a = 1; a < 100; a = a + 1) {
    int d = a * b + c;
    System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}
```

The math function and loop work but I can't figure out how to publish the nth term.
So far I have read array's are the most suitable solution but after much messing around removed the print array part, and decided to ask for help.

Thanks All

EDIT: addition of original code (it's kinda silly hence why I didn't publish it 1st time

```
public class PrimeNumberCounter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Define integers
int a = 1;
final int b = 2;
final int c = 3;
// Define Array.
int[] nth;
nth = new int[100];
    //Set loop
    for (a = 1; a < 100; a = a + 1) {
    nth[] = a * b + c;
    System.out.println(nth);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays can't expand dynamically

Comment: Don't remove what you tried that didn't work, show it! That's the best way for us to help. Please edit your post to include it. Also be more clear about what exactly you are stuck on. Are you trying to store the values you are printing out in the array?

Comment: original code now added so you can see my noobness

Comment: When you try to put something in the array you need to tell it what index or position to put it at. Something like `nth[a] = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are not trying to increase the size of the array, what you are trying to do is increase a counter that iterates through the array and assigns the result of the `d = a * b + c;` equation to the ith element of the array. Then after all the elements in the array have been populated, you want to iterate through the array an print all the values. If that is the case you can modify your code as follows:

```
public class PrimeNumberCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define integers
        int a = 1;
        final int b = 2;
        final int c = 3;
        //int d = 0; // not used
        // Define Array assuming that its size is fixed to 100
        int[] nth = new int[100];
        // Set the assignment loop
        for (a = 1; a <= nth.length; ++a) {
            // array indexing starts at 0
            nth[a - 1] = a * b + c;
        }
        // print loop
        for (int i = 0; i < nth.length; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", i + 1, nth[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't know the size of the array a priori you can use an ArrayList instead which can grow dynamically as mentioned in the comments and previous answer.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimeNumberCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define integers
        int a = 1;
        final int b = 2;
        final int c = 3;
        // Some size N let's assume it's a 100 again
        List<Integer> nth = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // Set the assignment loop
        for (a = 1; a <= 100; ++a) {
            // array indexing starts at 0
            nth.add(a - 1, a * b + c);
        }
        // print loop
        for (int i = 0; i < nth.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", i + 1, nth.get[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great, is it possible to also print what iteration it is so i can see the nth term as well as the result or value?

Comment: @StefanPAuckland yes it is possible I've updated the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use some collection like a list instead of using array.

You can use an iterator to iterate over that list and update the iterator.